# How to prevent Kubernetes horizontal auto-scaler from scaling down?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod

I have created a horizontal auto-scaler based on the cpu usage and it works fine. I want to know how I can configure the autoscaler in a way that it just scales up without scaling down? The reason I want such a thing is when I have high load/request I create some operators but I want to keep them alive even if for some amount of time they don't do anything but auto-scaler kills the pods and scaling down to the minimum replicas after sometime if there is no load.

My autoscaler:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: gateway
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: gateway
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 20
```

Edit:
By operator, I mean small applications/programs that are running in a pod.

Comment: What do you mean by operators? Is it the framework to do the post processing steps for stateful containers?

Comment: Why don't you simply lock the min number of pod at the value you wish to have? You may have another issue if your targetCpu is at 20... you may want to use another value as a scale up target....

Comment: I edited my question and added what I mean by an operator. @night-gold I don't want to reserve resources and I want to scale only if I need it but I want keep alive those small programs that are running in a scaled up pod in case I need them again, like in 10-20 minutes. I found these flags: `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization` and `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-delay` that I think can be helpful to solve my problem. That 20 is just for test and benchmarking and not for production.

Comment: @AVarf did you figure out how to add `horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-delay` into helm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization` flag to kube-controller-manager as described [in docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay). Default delay is set to 5 minutes.

To add flag to kube-controller-manager edit `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` on master node, pod will be then recreated.

Comment: is there a way to add this to helm?